# Can I join my 2 select queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have 2 tables:

**Task:**

```
id   title   description   client_id
```

**Clients:**

```
id   name   phone   email   url
```

When I click a task in my PHP application i open a new page where i also send the id of the clicked task.

To get the information from my tables I do this:

```
$task_id = null;
if (! empty ( $_GET ['task_id'] )) {
    $task_id = $_GET ['task_id'];
}
if ($task_id == null) {
    die("This page can only be accessed by selecting a task");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE id=:id";
$query = $db->prepare ( $sql );
$query->bindParam ( ":id", $task_id );
$query->execute ();
$task = $query->fetch ();

$client_id = $task ["client_id"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=:client_id";
$query = $db->prepare ( $sql );
$query->bindParam ( ":client_id", $client_id );
$query->execute ();
$client = $query->fetch ();
```

So, my question here is, can I use one SELECT instead of my current two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, by joining the two tables. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM task
    LEFT JOIN clients
    ON task.client_id=clients.id
    WHERE task.id=:id
```

Or in your PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task LEFT JOIN clients ON task.client_id=clients.id WHERE task.id=:id";
$query = $db->prepare ( $sql );
$query->bindParam ( ":id", $task_id );
$query->execute ();
$task = $query->fetch ();
```

Comment: Wauw, that was quick. It's working. I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using a subquery, or as Robby suggested, using a join.
Subquery example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = (SELECT client_id FROM task WHERE :task_id LIMIT 1)";
$query = $db->prepare ( $sql );
$query->bindParam ( ":task_id", $task_id );
$query->execute ();
$client = $query->fetch ();
```

Which one of these is more appropriate will likely depend on your use case.  Either should fix your problem, as stated.

Comment: That will not return any of the task data though, only the client data.

Comment: True.  I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that the primary goal was to fetch the client data.

Your solution would be preferable if he actually needs both, although if it were me, and I needed both, I'd use his original code and do the operation in two queries, because I think it would make the code easier to read later.